# React Navigation; use image in header?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation in a react native project and I want to customize the header with an image.

For a color I can use simple styling, but since react native doesn't support background images I need a different solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update:**

Since v2 of the library there's an special option for setting the header background, namely `headerBackground`.

This option accepts a React component, so when set to an `Image` component, it will use that.

For example:

```jsx
export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerBackground: () => (
      <Image
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }}
      />
    ),
  }
});
```

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@koen/react-navigation-header-background

---

**Old answer, for when still using React Navigation v1:**

Creating a custom header with an image is actually really simple.

By wrapping the Header with a view and placing an absolute positioned image in that view, the image will scale to its parent size.

Important is to set the `backgroundColor` of the default header to `transparent`.

```jsx
const ImageHeader = props => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }}>
    <Image
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }}
    />
    <Header {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}/>
  </View>
);
```

And then use that component as header:

```jsx
const SimpleStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    header: (props) => <ImageHeader {...props} />,
  }
});
```

Which would result in:

[image][image]

Comment: what if a still need my back button?

Comment: Shouldn't be affected by this, since it's just a background, with the original header on top

Comment: Does not work. Image stretches across the whole screen, doesn't fit inside the nav bar.

Comment: @jskidd3 this answer if from over a year ago, the library changed a lot in that time. At the time of writing this worked. I'll update my answer with a solution for v2 of the library.

Comment: @Koen Thanks so much!

Comment: @jskidd3 please upvote my answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: @Koen What are the values for stylesheet.absoluteFill?

Comment: @Larney here are the values of StylesSheet.absoluteFill: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill

Comment: The example above throws a warning "'headerBackground: <SomeElement />' will be removed in a future version. Use 'headerBackground: () => <SomeElement />' instead "

Answer (score 11):

According to the official docs of react-navigation v5, it can be implemented as follows:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    // title: 'App Name'
    options={{ 
     headerTitle: (props) => ( // App Logo
      <Image
        style={{ width: 200, height: 50 }}
        source={require('../assets/images/app-logo-1.png')}
        resizeMode='contain'
      />
    ),
    headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, textAlign: 'center' },
    }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update for React Navigation v5! (making this post for future references)**

For react navigation 5, I found this solution.

In StackNavigator.js class you can set a different image for each page (Stack.Screen):

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name='Home' 
    component={HomeScreen} 
    options={{ 
      title: <Image style={{ width: 250, height: 50 }}
      source = require('../images/yourimage.png')}/> 
    }}
 />
```

Then, you must adjust width, height, and position of the image, but it works! I think it's the simpliest way. Here's the output (yes, it's my image, before adjustments).

[image]

Don't forget to import Image!

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: I'm using version 5 also and I have this ain't working, no error but nothing is showing

Comment: Have you imported Image? import { Image } from 'react-native'

Answer (score 1):

headerBackground: () =>{
return(
<Image
style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }}
/>
)
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).