# React Navigation - Gradient color for Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, node-modules

I am using React Navigation in React Native app and I want to change the `backgroundColor` for the header to be gradient and I found out there is a node module : `react-native-linear-gradient` to achieve gradient in react native.

I have Root **StackNavigator** like that :

```
const Router = StackNavigator({

Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
       headerTitle: <Text>SomeTitle</Text>
       headerLeft: <SearchAndAgent />,
       headerRight: <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => { null }
    </TouchableOpacity>,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#005D97' },
    }),
},
});
```

I can wrap `Text` or `View` to be gradient like that :

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#3076A7', '#19398A']}><Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text></LinearGradient>,
```

How can I wrap the header background in the `navigationOptions` to use
the the `LinearGradient` module?

I know that I can create a custom header component and use it but when I am doing it all the native navigation animations from React Navigation not working like the Title Animation between two Routes so its not helping me.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution of Mark P was right but now you need to define headerStyle and do the absolute positioning there:

```
navigationOptions: {
  header: props => <GradientHeader {...props} />,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
},
```

and the GradientHeader:

```
const GradientHeader = props => (
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }}>
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['red', 'blue']}
      style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { height: Header.HEIGHT }]}
    >
      <Header {...props} />
    </LinearGradient>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: When I implement this, I keep having a probleme , the red screen saying that : TypeError : undefined is not a object (evaluation 'this.props.scene.index')
this errir is located at :
in Header (at withOrientation.js 30)...
......
......
Please help me, 
my react version is 0,55, is this the issue ?

Comment: @G.Adnane This is probably because you are using the latest version of react navigation (v2). They changed a lot in the navigator components there.

Comment: any idea how to implements it ?! And thank you by the way

Answer (score 47):

Just for your information, now with `headerBackground` props it's a way easier.

You can have a gradient header just doing this :

```
navigationOptions: {
  headerBackground: (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#a13388', '#10356c']}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
      end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
    />
  ),
  headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
}
```

This solution works good even with SafeArea for IosX

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed much easier using react-navigation 2.x

Comment: Nice one very easy

Answer (score 5):

Similar to this issue: [React Navigation; use image in header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097144/react-navigation-use-image-in-header)

For a Linear Gradient you would simply do >

`//imports`

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-navigation' ;
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
```

`//header`

Create the Header component which is wrapped in the Linear Gradient. 
by making the header `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` you will then show the Linear Gradient wrapping it.

```
const GradientHeader = props => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }}>
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#00a8c3', '#00373f']}
      style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.linearGradient]}
    />
    <Header {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}/>
  </View>
);
```

Return the screen with the header being your `GradientHeader` component.

```
const SimpleStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    header: (props) => <GradientHeader {...props} />,
  }
});
```

Should look something like this with the above code.

[Gradient Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4t3.png)

Comment: This will work as long as you give it a height to both the <Header> and <LinearGradient> components

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearGradient` component from the expo. It is a useful component and you can't install another library like react-native-linear-gradient. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/. By the way, you can change the back button. It is easy.

You can implement it on inside screen with navigationOptions like that

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: any) => {
  const onGoBack = () => navigation.goBack();
  return {
    header: (props: any) => <GradientHeader {...props} />,
    headerStyle: { height: 68, backgroundColor: "transparent", color: colors.white },
    headerTitle: "Sign Up",
    headerTitleStyle: { color: colors.white, fontSize: 18 },
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 32, height: 32, paddingLeft: 8 }} onPress={onGoBack}>
        <Image source={images.back} resizeMode="center" style={{ width: 32, height: 32 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  };
};
```