# Linear Gradient on react-navigation BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, linear-gradients

I'm trying to apply a linear gradient to a BottomTabNavigator from `react-navigation` v2. I attempted to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924323/react-navigation-gradient-color-for-header) using `createBottomTabNavigator` and [Expo LinearGradient](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/sdk/linear-gradient), but I'm getting the error shown below:

[image: Error]

Here is my code:

```
const GradientTab = props => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['white', 'rgba(214,234,241,0.77)']}
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    height: 72
                }}
            >
                <TabBarBottom {...props} />
            </LinearGradient>
        </View >
    )
};

export default AuthorizedNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    routeConfigs, 
    {
        tabBarComponent: GradientTab,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                height: 72,
                backgroundColor: 'white'
            }
        },
        initialRouteName: 'Home'
    }
);
```

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried declaring a width in GradientTab just to see if the error goes away?

Comment: @GavinThomas Yes, but the error is still the same. I tried checking if TabBarBottom is the right component the navigator expects to receive.