# React Native - Applying gradient to Navigation TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, gradient

I'm using React Navigation and trying to apply a linear gradient from white to transparent to the tab navigator and have it sit at the bottom of the screen.

I've found a good solution for using react-native-linear-gradient with a navigation header here: [React Navigation - Gradient color for Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924323/react-navigation-gradient-color-for-header?noredirect=1&lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

What isn't clear to me is how to apply this same logic to the tabBar. I tried defining a component like in the linked example and then passing that to backgroundColor, but it threw an error.

Here's my current code for the tabBarOptions:

```
{
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'rgba(248, 164, 2, 0.6)',  // Color of tab when pressed
  inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', // Color of tab when not pressed
  showLabel: false,
  indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)',
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    height: dynamicSize(60),
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  },
},
```

},

I then pass this into the StackNavigator by defining tabs as:

```
tabs: {
  screen: TabVisibleNavigator
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with a hack that seems to work fine:

- In the tabBarOptions style set backgroundColor to transparent; positioning to absolute
- Create gradient png image, save as an asset in the project
- Load png as an element in the bottom of the main View container
- Set png style as absolute so that it renders over the background container view

This will load a transparent tab bar over a gradient image. Not the most elegant solution but hopefully it helps someone stuck on the same problem.