# Add Gradiant color In Headerbar || React native || expo-linear-gradient

Tags: react-native

I need to add Gradient color in Header bar(Stack navigator). For that, I have installed expo-linear-gradient package. Basically its working as expected in JSX, but not in Headerbar.

```
const HeaderStyling = {
headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: () => (
        <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(227 ,253 ,250 ,0.5)', 'rgba(197 ,247 ,243 ,1)', 'rgba(196, 218, 253, 1)']}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        />
    ),
},
}
<HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={HeaderStyling}>
<HomeStack.Screen name="dashboard" options={{
    }} component={Dashboard} />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
```

Followed as per this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143985/6790135

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your navigation version if it's new https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#header-related-options check here and here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#options headerStyleInterpolator. Because navigation changed the how options behave and renamed after.